# Rails - Devise send user email after sign_up/create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm fairly new to rails and trying to figure things out. I recently got a mailer all setup and it was working fine. But I am trying to add a second mailer for user actions and it doesnt seem to work.

What I am trying to achieve is that a user signs up, it sends an email to the administrator, then the admin must enable the user. Currently when the admin enables the user it will send them an email, but for some reason my newly created user email does not fire. I think this is because my create method does not fire, where should I put it? Do I need to overwrite a user method?

My UserMailer controller:

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "website@rnd.designcom.com.au"
  def send_enabled_message(user)
    @user = user
    mail(:to => user.email, :subject => "Welcome to Pixel Technologies!!!")
  end
  def send_new_user_message(user)
    @user = user
    mail(:to => 'ben.suryn@rnd.designcom.com.au', :subject => "New User created please review and enable.")
  end
end
```

My users_controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!
  load_and_authorize_resource

# POST /users
def create
  @user = User.new(user_params)
  puts "******************** NEW USER ****************************"
  puts user_params
  if @user.save
    puts 'Sending email for create user'
    UserMailer.send_new_user_message(@user).deliver
    redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.'
  else
    render action: 'new'
  end
end
```

But this create method never gets fired. What am I donig wrong. Is there another method I need to put UserMailer.send_new_user_message(@user).deliver?

Comment: When the user signs up is the user created at that point? If so then perhaps your email should be sent on the user update method if the admin somehow enables the user, hard to see from this with out the whole flow...

Answer (score 47, accepted):

When users sign up with Devise, they don't go through the `UsersController`.

You might want to add the mail sending code in the `User` model.

For example, in `app/models/user.rb`:

```rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ...

  after_create :send_admin_mail
  def send_admin_mail
    UserMailer.send_new_user_message(self).deliver
  end

  # ...
end
```

This is done by utilizing the Active Record `after_create` callback.

Comment: This callback way is better in my opinion. +1

Comment: Excellent.  Quick and dirty.  Works great.

Comment: If this fails the transaction will be rolled back and object won't be saved to the db. How about using after_commit instead of after_create?

Comment: after_commit runs on update and destroy too, so it's not a good idea. Is there a way to prevent rollback?

Comment: @RahulRoy In Rails 4, you can add `true` to the end of the method. In Rails 5, callbacks won't stop unless `:abort` is `throw`n.

Answer (score 71):

Confirmation emails should be sent from the controller. It's simple to override the `Devise::RegistrationsController` defaults.

Create the file `app/controllers/my_registrations_controller.rb` (name this whatever you want)

```
class MyRegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  def create
    super
    if @user.persisted?
      UserMailer.new_registration(@user).deliver
    end
  end

end
```

Then in your routes:

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => "my_registrations" }
```

Comment: You should add `if @user.errors.empty?`, otherwise you'll be sending emails even if the registration was unsuccessful

Comment: @AlexSiri @Dex IMO it might be a better idea to use `@user.persisted?` to verify that the user was actually persisted to the database - almost certainly the behavior will be the same, but it's safer and I think the intention is clearer.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. The controller is a much more suitable place to send emails from than the model.

Comment: I agree that in many cases we should send emails from the controller. But if you use devise, you are actually sending user notification emails from the model. My answer meant to follow the convention.

Comment: @Domon I prefer not to spam when I generate users from seeds. Model object may be created in different ways, not only from user interaction.