# Error finding database user.email with ActionMailer / Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, email, devise, actionmailer

My end goal is to send an email when a Ticket has been created. It works perfectly when I am using one email address that I manually type in but as soon as I try to go through the database to pull the email addresses of users who have signed up, I get an error that says: undefined method `email' for nil:NilClass

I am sure this is a simple solution but I keep getting lost and going in circles. Here is the code of where I am at - Ticket Controller:

```
def create
@ticket = Ticket.new(params[:ticket])

respond_to do |format|
  if @ticket.save
    TicketMailer.ticketcreated_email(@user).deliver
    format.html { redirect_to @ticket, notice: 'Ticket was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render json: @ticket, status: :created, location: @ticket }
  else
    format.html { render action: "new" }
    format.json { render json: @ticket.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end
```

ticket_mailer.rb

```
class TicketMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default :from => "myemailaddress@gmail.com"

  def ticketcreated_email(user)
    mail(:to => user.email, :subject => "Simple Test")
  end
end
```

The mail files / etc all if I just replace the "user.email" in the ticket_mailer.rb with my email address. But, as soon as I reach for my users built out with Devise, I can't get their data.

Comment: I should mention, I want to send the same email to all the users except I do want to change out the user information (link / etc).

Comment: Also had looked at this but since it isn't based on a user creation it doesn't work the way I need: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17479864/rails-devise-send-user-email-after-sign-up-create)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want the email to be sent to the current user?  You may want to try:

```
TicketMailer.ticketcreated_email(current_user).deliver
```

Or, if you want a custom email for each user you'll probably want a loop:

```
users=User.all
users.each do |user|
  mail(:to => user.email, :subject => "Simple Test")
end
```

Splitting the work between the controller and class might look like:

Controller:

```
 if @ticket.save
    users=User.all
    users.each do |user|
      TicketMailer.ticketcreated_email(user).deliver
    end
    format.html { redirect_to @ticket, notice: 'Ticket was successfully created.' }
```

Class:

```
  def ticketcreated_email(user)
    mail(:to => user.email, :subject => "Simple Test")
  end
```

Comment: No, my goal is to send it to all users: User.all

Comment: Then you will probably need a loop where you build the email for each user.  I've edited my answer to give an example.

Comment: How do I handle that in the controller? Or are you stating that it should be in the ticket_mailer.rb?

Comment: If you want your `ticketcreated_email` to be per-one-user, you could do `users=User.all` in your controller and then pass this in to `ticketcreated_email(users)` where you'd use the `user.each` loop to build an email for all the users that were given.

Comment: Worked like a charm, thanks! Adding the final results now to this.

Comment: Cool.  I kind of messed it up when I was trying to describe it in the last comment and I added one more example to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with this process as the result thanks to @cschroed

```
def create
@ticket = Ticket.new(params[:ticket])

respond_to do |format|
  if @ticket.save
    user=User.all
    user.each do |user|
       TicketMailer.ticketcreated_email(user).deliver
    end
    format.html { redirect_to @ticket, notice: 'Ticket was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render json: @ticket, status: :created, location: @ticket }
  else
    format.html { render action: "new" }
    format.json { render json: @ticket.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end
```