# access "self" from view after sending mail (ruby on rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

After a user signs up (Devise RegistrationController), I want to send them a welcome email.

Inside my User model, I created a function:

```
 def send_welcome_email
    UserMailer.welcome(self).deliver
  end
```

Then I've added `after_create :send_welcome_email`

Inside the email view, I need to access variables.

```
<p><span><strong>Hi <%= self.name %>,</strong></span></p>
```

Returns an error:

```
undefined method `name' for #<#<Class:0x00007fa7d18e13b0>:0x00007fa7e4025358>
```

It makes sense that this would result in the error above, but I'm not sure how I can access variables from the model (that was just created).

I was following this asnwer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17480095/9200273

Welcome method:

```
def welcome(user)
    mail(
      to: user.email,
      subject: 'Welcome to Site!',
      from: "support@site.com"
  )
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass objects to the Mailer class using the `with` method like this:

```
UserMailer.with(user: self).welcome.deliver
```

Inside the UserMailer class:

```
def welcome_email
  @user = params[:user]
  ...
end
```

In the view:

```
<%= @user.name %>
```

Reference: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html

Comment: Perfect. Exactly what I needed. Thank you very much!

Comment: @good_afternoon Np, remember to accept to answer to help future people with the same question.

Comment: had to wait 5 minutes :)